# Quero pegar uma data de Abertura e fechamento, So que qd faço o update so para a data de fechamento ele automaticamente atualiza as duas datas

Tags: data, spring, sql-update, spring-data, spring-jpa

package com.deyvisson.os.domain;

@Entity
public class OS {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
private Date dataAbertura;
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
private Date dataFechamento;

private Integer prioridade;
private String obs;
private Integer status;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "tecnico_id")
private Tecnico tecnico;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cliente_id")
private Cliente cliente;

public OS() {
    super();
    this.setDataAbertura(new Date());
    this.setPrioridade(Prioridade.BAIXA);
    this.setStatus(Status.ABERTO);
}

public OS(Integer id, Date dataAbertura,Integer prioridade, String obs, Integer status , Tecnico tecnico, Cliente cliente) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.dataAbertura = dataAbertura;
//  this.prioridade = (prioridade == null) ? 0 : prioridade.getCod();
    this.prioridade = prioridade;
    this.obs = obs;
//  this.status = (status == null) ? 0 : status.getCod();
    this.status = status;
    this.tecnico = tecnico;
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getDataAbertura() {
    return dataAbertura;
}

public void setDataAbertura(Date dataAbertura) {
    this.dataAbertura = dataAbertura;
}

public Date getDataFechamento() {
    return dataFechamento;
}

public void setDataFechamento(Date dataFechamento) {
    this.dataFechamento = dataFechamento;
}

public Prioridade getPrioridade() {
    return Prioridade.toEnum(this.prioridade);
}

public void setPrioridade(Prioridade prioridade) {
    this.prioridade = prioridade.getCod();
}

public String getObs() {
    return obs;
}

public void setObs(String obs) {
    this.obs = obs;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return Status.toEnum(this.status);
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status.getCod();
}

public Tecnico getTenico() {
    return tecnico;
}

public void setTenico(Tecnico tenico) {
    this.tecnico = tenico;
}

public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    OS other = (OS) obj;
    return Objects.equals(id, other.id);
}
```

}

-------------- DTO ------------
package com.deyvisson.os.dtos;

public class OsDTO implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer id;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
private Date dataAbertura;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
private Date dataFechamento;

private Integer prioridade;
@NotEmpty(message = "O campo observações ele é requerido")
private String observacao;
private Integer status;
private Integer tecnico;
private Integer cliente;

public OsDTO() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public OsDTO(OS obj) {
    super();
    this.id = obj.getId();
    this.dataAbertura = obj.getDataAbertura();
    this.dataFechamento = obj.getDataFechamento();
    this.prioridade = obj.getPrioridade().getCod();
    this.observacao = obj.getObs();
    this.status = obj.getStatus().getCod();
    this.tecnico = obj.getTenico().getId();
    this.cliente = obj.getCliente().getId();
}


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getDataAbertura() {
    return dataAbertura;
}

public void setDataAbertura(Date dataAbertura) {
    this.dataAbertura = dataAbertura;
}

public Date getDataFechamento() {
    return dataFechamento;
}

public void setDataFechamento(Date dataFechamento) {
    this.dataFechamento = dataFechamento;
}

public Prioridade getPrioridade() {
    return Prioridade.toEnum(this.prioridade);
}

public void setPrioridade(Integer prioridade) {
    this.prioridade = prioridade;
}

public String getObservacao() {
    return observacao;
}

public void setObservacao(String observacao) {
    this.observacao = observacao;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return Status.toEnum(this.status);
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Integer getTecnico() {
    return tecnico;
}

public void setTecnico(Integer tecnico) {
    this.tecnico = tecnico;
}

public Integer getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(Integer cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}
```

}

---- SERVICE ---------------

@Service
public class OsService {

```
@Autowired
private OSRepository repository;

@Autowired
private ClienteService clienteService;

@Autowired
private TecnicoService tecnicoService;

public OS create(@Valid OsDTO obj) { // Criando
    return fromDTO(obj);
}

public OS update(@Valid OsDTO2 obj2) { // Atualizando

    findByid(obj2.getId());
    return fromDTO2(obj2);
}

private OS fromDTO(OsDTO obj) { // Método para Criar

    OS newOBJ = new OS();
    newOBJ.setId(obj.getId());
    newOBJ.setDataAbertura(new Date());;
    newOBJ.setObs(obj.getObservacao());
    newOBJ.setPrioridade(Prioridade.toEnum(obj.getPrioridade().getCod()));
    newOBJ.setStatus(Status.toEnum(obj.getStatus().getCod()));
    newOBJ.setId(obj.getId());

    Tecnico tec = tecnicoService.findById(obj.getTecnico());
    Cliente cli = clienteService.findById(obj.getCliente());

    newOBJ.setCliente(cli);
    newOBJ.setTenico(tec);

    return repository.save(newOBJ);
}

private OS fromDTO2 (OsDTO2 obj) { // Método para Atualizar

    OS newOBJ2 = new OS();
    newOBJ2.setId(obj.getId());
    newOBJ2.setObs(obj.getObservacao());
    newOBJ2.setPrioridade(Prioridade.toEnum(obj.getPrioridade().getCod()));
    newOBJ2.setStatus(Status.toEnum(obj.getStatus().getCod()));

    Tecnico tec2 = tecnicoService.findById(obj.getTecnico());
    Cliente cli2 = clienteService.findById(obj.getCliente());

    newOBJ2.setCliente(cli2);
    newOBJ2.setTenico(tec2);
```

// Essa condição significa, se o Status q é igual a 2(Encerrado) ele pegara a data atual

```
    if (newOBJ2.getStatus().getCod().equals(2)) { 

        newOBJ2.setDataFechamento(new Date());
    }

    return repository.save(newOBJ2);
}
```

}

------- Resource --------

package com.deyvisson.os.resources;

@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/os")
public class OsResource {

```
@Autowired
private OsService service;


//Atualiza a OS
@PutMapping
public ResponseEntity<OsDTO2> update(@Valid @RequestBody OsDTO2 obj){
    obj = new OsDTO2(service.update(obj));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);
}
```

}

Comment: O problema possa estar no seu método de `atualizar`, pois você cria um novo objeto desse tipo `OS newOBJ2 = new OS()`, e isso ele faz um new DateTime pelo motivo de você estar com dois construtores um que tem o `super` e o outro não, o que tem o `super` ele atribuiu um novo Date para a data de abetura e que faça a inserção da dataAbertura nova. O certo seria você atualizar o objeto já existente, apenas alterando a data de fechadura.

Comment: E outra, veja este post para melhorar as suas perguntas [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que sua dúvida chegue para mais pessoas, também, ao fazer uma pergunta, coloque apenas o que é necessário, não precisa colocar toda a classe, se o seu ponto é datas, coloque apenas as coisas que envolvem ou manuseiam os campos de data.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.